# How to specify width and height of plot in R without using the parameters when opening the window

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to open a plot maximized.

I didn't find how to do that, but I can get there with width and height. e.g. I call `X11()`, maximize the window, call `dev.size()`, and then put those in manually, e.g. `X11(width=25.8,height=14.3)`. Only that differs from machine to machine. So I'd like to define it in "Resources", as mentioned in the help:

```
the width and height of the plotting window, in inches.
If NA, taken from the resources and if not specified there
defaults to 7 inches. See also ‘Resources’.
```

Except I don't know how to "See also Resources". `?Resources` doesn't work...

Some googling led to this:

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"), 
  function(...) grDevices::X11.options(width=25.8, height=14.3,type="xlib"))
```

Except it isn't working for me...

The aim in the end would be to place a maximized function into each machine's `.Rprofile`.

For now I can get around that by just saving `width` and `height` in the `.Rprofile`, but still...

Thanks

Comment: What version of R and what OS is this for?

Comment: Ubuntu, and R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"

Comment: Reading the rest of the help will help. :) There is a 'Resources' heading with a pointer to the X man page (which includes a section on geometry) as well as a small example ‘~/.Xresources’ entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments, this is the way to do it:

```
X11.options(width=20,height=10)
```